# Как компилировать kivymd приложение под Windows

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd, auto-py-to-exe

[image: Вот такую ошибку выдает, чтобы я не делал, она преследует меня]

Я пытался поставить другую версию python, танцевал с бубном, пробовал auto-py-to-exe, pyinstaller, делал файл .spec вручную, но ничего не получается. Возможно kivymd не поддерживает компиляцию под windows? Но мне нужно именно kivymd для таблицы. В моем не большом проекте main.py, search.py(файл, который парсит данные для таблицы), my.kv и одна картинка. Пробовал все, что нашел в интернете сам, поэтому пишу сюда, умным людям.

Comment: Так дело в вашем коде, а кода нет. Где-то у вас там есть бесконечная рекурсия; где — это уж вам видней.

Comment: код работает отлично

Comment: Хм, тогда действительно странно. Попробуйте написать iisue разрабам библиотеки на гитхаб.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю в `kivy` это уже исправлено ([issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8074)). Возможно используется более ранняя версия `kivy` тогда можно воспользоваться решением приведённым в issue.

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли!